# Parse error when return json record with ajax call

Tags: php, json, jquery

I am still new on understanding the concept of MVC, Ajax, and how they work together to call data from the database, please bear with me :)

I have encountered the error of:

> parse errror syntax error Unexpected token < [object, object]

when I return the value from the database.

I am not sure:

1. Did I pass data correctly from ajax to the query to be parsed, since I used bindParam so that the variable can be post correctly, but I do not see any result is generated.
2. Did I format the ajax call correctly?

**Server Side**

quiz_controller.php

```
switch($_POST['action']) {
case 'get_users':
    print $users->getUsers($questID);
break;
}
```

Quiz.php

```
$questID = $db->$_POST['qid'];

class Quiz {

private $dbh;

public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$db)  {       
    $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db,$user,$pass);       
}

//getQuestion : To get single questions related fields
public function getUsers(){             
    //$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT a.questID, a.questTitle, a.questDesc, b.qCatName,c.qTypTitle FROM eq_question AS a INNER JOIN eq_question_category AS b ON a.qCatID = b.qCatID INNER JOIN eq_question_type AS c ON a.qTypID WHERE questID= $questID ");
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT a.questID, a.questTitle, a.questDesc, b.qCatName,c.qTypTitle FROM eq_question AS a INNER JOIN eq_question_category AS b ON a.qCatID = b.qCatID INNER JOIN eq_question_type AS c ON a.qTypID WHERE questID= :parameter ");
    //$sth->bindParam(':parameter', $questID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(':parameter', $questID);
    $sth->execute();
    return json_encode($sth->fetchAll());
}
```

**Client Side**

quiz_controller.js

```
$(function() {  
    $(document).on("click", "button#ct", function(){ getUserList(this); }); 
}

function getUserList(element) {
    alert('worked!');
    $('#indicator').show();
    qid = 3;
    alert('worked assign qid    !');
    alert(qid+'is the qid');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../equizz/app/controller/quiz_controller.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
             "questID":qid, //page: value in the url php  : currentpage: value in js 
             //action: 'get_users'
             action: 'get_users'
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert('data now is '+data);
                renderUserList(data);
                $('#indicator').hide();
            },//success: function(data) END
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert('error!');
                alert(textStatus+"  " + errorThrown +"  " + XMLHttpRequest); 
            } //error END

        });//$.ajax() END
}//getUserList END
function renderUserList(jsonData) {
    //ACW- instead of generate a new table of content. Replace content inside related ID fields!
    var table = '</nav><!--Top Navigation END--><div class="content black"><div class="title dark-gray-text black grid-parent"><div class="grid-100">';
    $.each( jsonData, function( index, user){
        table += '<h2 class="title-2" id="qNumberv">'+'Question No.'+user.questID+'</h2>';
        table += '</div><div class="grid-100 grid-parent">';
        table += '<h1 class="grid-33 mobile-grid-50 " id="qCatv"><!--Question Category-->'+user.qCatName+'</h1>';
        table += '<h1 class="center-4text grid-33 mobile-grid-50-text4right " id="strikesv"><!--Strikes-->'+'00 Strikes'+'</h1>';
        table += '<h1 class="right right-title right-4text grid-33 mobile-grid-50-text4right " id="scorev"><!--Score-->'+'00 Scores'+'</h1</div></div><!--title END-->';
        table += '<section class="question-content"><!--Question Details--><h3 class="question shadow-body grid-100" id="qTitlev" ><!--Question Title-->'+user.questTitle+'</h3>';
        table += '<!--Question Description--><p class="question-detail shadow-body grid-100" id="qDescv" >'+user.questDesc+'</p></section></div><!--content END-->';    
    }); 
    $('div#qcontent').html(table);


}
```

Additional info:

1. (**FIXED**)the alert's error shows `parse errror syntax error Unexpected token < [object, object]`
2. that `prevenDefault()` about, its about the line where says `$.each( jsonData, function( index, user){` but I do not know how to fix it.
3. The query itself is perfect, but I AM NOT SURE ABOUT the appliance of Perimeter!

**Update:**

I found the status of my call to the controller file is below:

```
Request URL:http:.../app/controller/quiz_controller.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:26
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:PHPSESSID=fpm2m9kl4rd8ijgvqlkmv0kvc5
Host:10.9.44.118
Origin:http://10.9.44.118
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http:.../app/equizz/public/index.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
questID:3
action:get_users
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:292
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 25 Nov 2013 16:19:43 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.7
```

NOTE: I replaced the actual path of file with ... for security reason.

Comment: I saw that you have a lot of alert() for debugging, what do you get for each one ?

Comment: In the browser developer tool console, you can able to see which line the error thrown?  check in chrome

Comment: `console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)`

Comment: Break the problem into 2 clean parts. Firstly, ensure that your PHP is returning correctly formatted json. If it is, it's a JS problem. If it's not, it's a PHP problem. Also check the response headers include `Content-Type: text/json`. I recommend the JSONView extension (Google it, available for FF/Chrome). It will format json into a tree in the browser for easier navigation. It also provides basic validation. Very handy for problems like this. You should also consider checking the "Net" tab in Firebug. You can see headers / response bodies and in FF can re-play Ajax POSTs in a new tab.

Comment: with chrome, open the developer panel, network tab and see what happens when you load the page. Can you see your ajax call ? what is the response from the server ?

Comment: Test the URL by browsing to it. Try changing `$_POST[...]` to `$_REQUEST[...]` - This will let you pass parameters in the url for testing... eg  `http://example.com/quiz_controller.php?action=get_users` - This will allow you to see the output of the PHP and remove Javascript/Client-side from the equation entirely. As @JeromeWAGNER mentioned, the Net tab in the dev panel is another way to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the bindParam line to

```
$sth->bindParam(':parameter', $_POST['qid']);
```

Fixed the rest.

Hope this can help someone has the same trouble :)

**Btw, I do not think its secured enough. Plz fix or add another answer if wish to perfect it thanks!**